# How to change the animation start and delay in libreoffice impress programmatically

Tags: python, libreoffice

I'm trying to add an animation to a texbox in the Impress using python. I've succeeded to add textbox and animation to it. But I cannot figure it out how to change several properties of animation, start and delay specifically:

```
......
doc = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

page = doc.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0)

text = doc.createInstance('com.sun.star.drawing.TextShape')

text.TextFitToSize = AUTOFIT

text.TextAutoGrowWidth = True

text.TextEffect = MOVE_FROM_TOP

page.add(text)
```

I know there's `EffectNodeType` enum which has the properties:

```
 constants EffectNodeType
 {
     const short DEFAULT = 0;

     const short ON_CLICK = 1;

     const short WITH_PREVIOUS = 2;

     const short AFTER_PREVIOUS = 3;

     const short MAIN_SEQUENCE = 4;

     const short TIMING_ROOT = 5;

     const short INTERACTIVE_SEQUENCE = 6;
 };
```

I guess it can be set on effect node. But how to access it using python?
These animation properties can be changed in gui:

[image]