# LibreOffice Impress macro to read a slide's animation event duration and delay times

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-impress, libreoffice-macros

I'm writing a basic macro in LibreOffice Impress which builds a custom slide show that will run for a specified length of time. The slide show consists of a set of auto-advancing slides. My problem is that if a slide includes animation e.g. a shape fade in, I can't find it's duration and delay times. Without these times I can't calculate how long the slide will be displayed for.

[image]

Using *PropertySetInfo* and *getPropertyByName()* method I've found the *Effect* property but there is no sign of *Duration* or *Delay* properties. Can somebody point me towards where they may be stored in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions were asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135355/how-to-change-the-animation-start-and-delay-in-libreoffice-impress-programmatica) and [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-you-change-the-animation-start-of-an-impress-object-in-a-macro/63773) with no solution.

The [MRI tool](https://github.com/hanya/MRI/releases) shows a property `TextAnimationDelay` for a shape that is documented as, "This is the delay in thousandths of a second between each of the animation steps." However, the value was 0. I also tried this, hoping to get the list of animations on a particular slide as shown at the top of the side panel, but it didn't have the expected number of elements:

```
oAnimationsEnum = oSlide.getAnimationNode().createEnumeration()
```

Instead of going through the API, you could unzip the .odp file and look for where the values are stored, similar to what is suggested [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-assign-animation-to-multiple-objects-with-delay-in-impress/18176):

> Find the relevant `anim:par` element.
> Set `smil:begin="1s"` on the relevant elements.

Once you figure out how to do it manually, write a script to do it automatically — unzip the file, then do the parsing. The basic idea requires only a few lines of Python code, although this particular task might require more code due to how the values in question are stored.

Since ultimately you need this information in a Basic macro, your script could print out a Basic language array of the values, which you could copy and paste into the macro code. The values would need to be generated again if the delays are changed.